# ArcPro 3.1 : Batch Calculate Field Syntax

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

ArcPro 3.1

I am currently attempting to run a batch process on about 200 shape files in which a new field (volume) will be calculated based on two other fields. All fields are the same in all of the shape files.

When I run the batch process I get a syntax error:invalid syntax (see image)

[image: image of error]

Field type is set correctly. I also attempted to add the field first (which had no errors), but obviously did not solve the problem.

I have noodled around with the syntax but I can't find anything online regarding what I might be doing wrong and am basically shooting in the dark.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else will know WHY this is. But I was able to solve this by changing the Expression type from Python3 to Arcade in the Geoprocessing dialogue window.